# MUI datagrid doesn't render rows despite rows existing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, datagrid

I today ran into an issue with datagrid in Material UI where despite rows existing, they aren't being shown anywhere. This is completely new to me as everything was working just fine yesterday, all I did between now and then was refactor some code.

Here's the component:

```js
const UserGrid: React.FC = () => {
  const reducer = useGrid();
  const { state } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { loading } = state.crudState;
  const { rowIds, sortState, filterState } = reducer.state;
  const users = state.users;
  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 100, editable: false },
    {
      field: "name",
      headerName: "Name",
      flex: 1,
    },
    {
      field: "email",
      headerName: "Email",
      flex: 1,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: "flex", height: "100%", p: 5 }}>
      <Box sx={{ m: "0 auto", flexGrow: 1, height: "600px" }}>
        {users && (
          <DataGrid
            columns={columns}
            loading={loading === "main"}
            rows={users}
            getRowId={(row) => row.id}
            onSelectionModelChange={(newSelection) => {
              reducer.dispatch({ type: "rowids", payload: newSelection });
            }}
            onSortModelChange={(newSortModel) => {
              reducer.dispatch({ type: "sort", payload: newSortModel });
            }}
            sortModel={sortState}
            checkboxSelection={true}
            filterModel={filterState}
            selectionModel={rowIds}
            components={{
              ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: SortAscIcon,
              ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: SortDescIcon,
              Toolbar: GridToolbar,
              Footer: GridFooter,
              Pagination: null,
            }}
            scrollbarSize={10}
            componentsProps={{
              toolbar: { rowIds: rowIds },
              baseCheckbox: { sx: { color: "primary.main" } },
              footer: {
                rowIds: rowIds,
              },
            }}
            autoPageSize
            disableSelectionOnClick
          />
        )}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Here's the reducer:

```js
const useUserActions = () => {
  const userActionReducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "main":
        return {
          ...state,
          users: action.payload?.body as User[],
          crudState: {
            ...state.crudState,
            ...(action.payload?.state as CrudState),
          },
        };
      case "remove":
        return {
          ...state,
          users: state.users?.filter(
            (user) => !action.payload?.ids?.includes(user.id)
          ),
          crudState: {
            ...state.crudState,
            ...(action.payload?.state as CrudState),
          },
          init: undefined,
        };
      case "add":
        return {
          ...state,
          users: [...(state.users || []), action.payload?.body as User],
          crudState: {
            ...state.crudState,
            ...(action.payload?.state as CrudState),
          },
          init: undefined,
        };
      case "init":
        return {
          ...state,
          init: action.payload?.init as Init,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userActionReducer, initialState);

  const setInit = (init: Init) => dispatch({ type: "init", payload: { init } });
  useEffect(() => {
    const api = new ApiClient();
    if (state.init) {
      state.init.query === "add" && userAddAction(state, dispatch, api);
      state.init.query === "remove" && userRemoveAction(state, dispatch, api);
    }
  }, [state]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const api = new ApiClient();
    const fetchUsers = userFetchAction(dispatch, api);
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);
  return { state: state, setInit: setInit };
};
```

And here's the relevant fetch function:

```js
export function userFetchAction(
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<Action>,
  api: ApiClient
) {
  return async () => {
    dispatch({ type: "main", payload: { state: { loading: "main" } } });
    await api
      .getUsers()
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((users) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "main",
          payload: { body: users, state: { loading: null } },
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "main",
          payload: {
            state: {
              error: [{
                message: error.detail,
                statusCode: error.statusCode,
                ...error,
              }],
              loading: null,
            },
          },
        });
      });
  };
}
```

I looked up this issue and found some suggesting to add a state to hold the data as it begins undefined, I did this with a useEffect, then removed it as it didn't work:

```js
const [ rows, setRows ] = useState<User[]>([])
useEffect(()=>{
  if (state.users.length) {
     setRows(state.users)
  }
}, [state])
```

The rows are clearly there, they just refuse to be shown.

I've tried both setting the height of the container and setting autoHeight on the grid without any results. I don't know what to do about it really, it might just be that I'm missing something very simple but can't find any info anywhere.

[image: Screenshot of react devtools showing rows exist]

[image: no rows rendered]

Answer (score 0):

So this is slightly embarrassing.

Turns out I had at some point added both autoPageSize and autoHeight to the default props in my theme so no matter what I did they were there and as they don't work together, that is what caused this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else showing up here in the future, I had the same problem.
This link ( https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/3546 ) helped me figure out that I was not declaring a height boolean on my component.

I'm rendering in a react application like so now and it works great.

```
<DataGrid columns={columns} rows={Object.values(tabledata[0])} autoHeight pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} checkboxSelection />
```

'autoHeight' was the boolean that I added.

Good luck!